# Mysql Query for Latest High Scores, not the Highest High scores

Tags: mysql

Edit: SOLVED by Ian & Mark...

The high scores for a game need to be fetched from a MySQL database (using php).
The query I use works fine for stats that always increase in time.
The query however does not work for stats that can go up or down in time.

**Some details:**

The stats for players are stored in the `stats` table. Multiple rows per player (all updates), an auto_increment column is Primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `stamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `kill` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `death` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `kdr` decimal(6,3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=956 ;
```

Some sample data:

```
1,  1365175892, user1,  1089,   191,    5.702
2,  1365175892, user2,  1805,   547,    6.709
3,  1365175892, user3,  104397, 2272,   45.949
4,  1365175892, user1,  1163,   200,    5.815
5,  1365175892, user2,  1090,   204,    5.343
```

The Kills & Deaths increment by time and thus it is simple to create a top 10.

**The issue**

For the Kill to Death Ratio (KDR), the value can go up or down in time.
Example: user2 in update 5 has a lower KDR that in update 2, but still my high score list shows the highest KDR of update 2, while I actually need the lower KDR from update 5.

So here, for the top 10, I do not need the Highest value (that would be automatically the last value stored for each player) but the LATEST value (that is not nescesarily the highest value).
And I can't get it to work...

One of the queries I tried is this one that works for increasing-only-stats:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stats AS s
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT username, MAX(kdr) AS kdr
        FROM stats
        GROUP BY username
    ) AS groupedstats
    ON s.username = groupedstats.username
    AND s.kdr = groupedstats.kdr
ORDER BY kdr DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Could anyone help me how to get the correct kdr high-score list? I'm lost...

Thanks

Comment: The latest one is the one with the highest id, right - in which case it beggars belief that you cannot solve this for yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the top 10 by kdr for the latest record for each user, try:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stats AS s
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT username, MAX(`stamp`) AS `stamp`
        FROM stats
        GROUP BY username
    ) AS groupedstats
    ON s.username = groupedstats.username
    AND s.`stamp` = groupedstats.`stamp`
ORDER BY kdr DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! You make it look so simple. And it is simple once you understand it.  Also, this query produces the exact same result as the answer from Ian Kenney above... Too bad I can't upvote because I don't have enough respect points

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
select * from stats where id in ( 
  select max(id) as maxid 
  from stats
  group by username
)
order by kdr desc limit 10
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! You make it look so simple. And it is simple once you understand it.  Also, this query produces the exact same result as the answer from Mark Bannister below... Too bad I can't upvote because I don't have enough respect points

Comment: Mark has answered the problem as asked ( working out the latest stamp).  I have taken a shortcut (maybe because I am a little lazy) and assumed the latest stamp will also have the highest id

Comment: FWIW, Mark Bannister's answer is likely to perform better - especially on larger data sets. I would have accepted his answer as the correct one. Also it's so similar to your own query (except that I'm sure it's meant to be MAX(id)) that it's wonder you couldn't figure it out for yourself ;-)